# I can connect only to the default postgresql db via remote client

Tags: postgresql, remote-access

I have postgresql on my VPS, and there are two databases, let me call them db1 and db2 (please note that db1 was created by default, while db2 was created by me). I can work with both when I access them via linux terminal on VPS, but when I try to connect to them via a client on my local PC, I encounter bizzare things: I completely successfully can connect to db1, BUT when I try to connect to db2, I have the following error message:

FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "/*some unknown ip; according to google, it is located somewhere far away from me*/", user "postgres", database "db2", SSL on

Can anyone help, please?

Let me underline that I have "host | samerole | all | 0.0.0.0/0 | md5" in pg_hba.conf and listen_addresses = '*' in postgresql.conf.

Please note that db1 is completely functional via client, so it is clear that the problem is not with general config file, but with db2... But I just can not get what the problem is. Please also note that in both cases I try to connect with my superuser credentials.

Comment: Can you show your entire *pg_hba.conf*, please?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html: "*The value `samerole` specifies that the requested user must be a member of the role with the same name as the requested database. Superusers are not considered to be members of a role for the purposes of `samerole` unless they are explicitly members of the role, directly or indirectly, and not just by virtue of being a superuser.*" - so likely you cannot connect as user `postgres` to database `db2`. Try to connect either as user `db2` to database `db2`, or as user `postgres` to database `postgres`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have just changed that setting to 'All', and now everything works.